# grails small customization to default scaffolding

Tags: grails

Using the default grails scaffold, what is the simplest way, or most effective way to make it so that the "level" field is between 0 and 5, as a select list drop-down?

Or, is it only possible to do if I install the Templates and customize them. I've read about this but don't want to do it unless necessary.

Here is the Domain Class:

```
package treetester
class CustomerDivisionTreeNode {
    String name
    int level

    CustomerDivisionTreeNode parent

    static constraints = {
        parent(nullable: true)      
      }

    static hasMany = [children: CustomerDivisionTreeNode]
    static mappedBy = [children:'parent']   
}
```

Here is the Controller Class

```
package treetester
class CustomerDivisionTreeNodeController {
    def scaffold = CustomerDivisionTreeNode     
}
```

I read in the docs, (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) you could do this...

> You can also get the generator to generate lists instead of text
>   inputs if you use the inList constraint:
>
> def constraints = {
>       title()
>       category(inList: ["Fiction", "Non-fiction", "Biography"])
>       releaseDate() }

so, logic tells me I'd want something like this:

level(inList:["0","1","2","3","4","5"])

But where to put it and make it work?

Comment: What do you mean with "scaffolding". As I understand, you need to make select with values. Why scaffolding?

Comment: @baxxabit: What I mean by "scaffolding" is Grails default Scaffolding, which renders the CRUD for this domain dynamically.  My question is, can I change how the dynamically generated pages (based on the default Scaffolding) appear? In this example, I'd like to change the "level" field from rendering as a plain <input type="text".../> to a <select> field. CAN I DO THIS AND USE THE DEFAULT SCAFFOLDING?

<aside> I am confused as to why anyone would down-vote this question</aside>

Comment: @baxxabit: Your question about scaffolding seems to indicate that you don't understand the Grails statement:  def scaffold = CustomerDivisionTreeNode

Comment: Maybe you're right :) Can you try to explain, how do you understand, how def scaffold = CustomerDivisionTreeNode works? What will happends?

Comment: Here's what the scaffold is:  http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html
Documentation describes a small set of customizations.  But docs are often slim and there are ways to do things not documented.  Hency my reason for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that I overlooked the min and max options for the constraints on the domain:  Here's how to get that on the GSP...

see the line
level nullable: true, min: 1, max: 5
below...

```
class CustomerDivisionLevel {

Integer level
String levelName
Customer customer

static belongsTo = [Customer]

static mapping = {
    id generator: "assigned"
}

static constraints = {
    level nullable: true, min: 1, max: 5
    levelName nullable: true, maxSize: 45
}
```

}